# Ubuntu 16.04 landscape keeps redirecting to wrong url

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, landscape, virtualhost

So I installed Landscape on an ubuntu 16.04 server.
The hostname of the server is: http://management.domain.com/

Everytime i try to access landscape by going to: http://management.domain.com/ It redirects me to: http://management/

The Landscape web interface is shown in my browser but if I click any button Landscape links back to: http://management.domain.com/ and Chrome or Edge start to complain about to many redirects.

When i look at the Vhost in apache it shows the right configuration for http://management.domain.com/

The root URL is set right too on the Landscape web interface. Does anyone know here how to prevent Landscape from redirecting http://management.domain.com/  to http://management/ ?

I couldn't find anything on the internet or forums. I also checked the docs of Landscape but i couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try to open your site in a new *incognito window*, if it working normal  then you should flush the cache of your browser.

Comment: @pa4080 that doesn't work. I tried it with different browsers, but all te same problem

Comment: "root url" is set correctly in the UI?  if so, do a `sudo lsctl restart` on the landscape server and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: As you can see in the question I did set the root url to the right url. It just looks like it strips everything after the first dot.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you and bumped into this post.

I believe at one point I entered `mySubdomain` and then later changed it to `mySubdomain.domain.com` so part of the application had the correct config and part didn't.

In any case, I found that I could edit the conf:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/mySubdomain.conf`

I replaced all occurrences of `mySubdomain` with `mySubdomain.domain.com`

Then I restarted apache (`sudo apachectl graceful`) and the web UI no longer had links pointing to `http://mySubdomain/`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I deleted my installation. But this gives me hope:) I will try to reinstall after the weekend to verify!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that may run into this in future, the lines in the apache site config file that determine the URL for Landscape's web UI are the two `RewriteRule` lines:

```
RewriteRule ^/message-system http://localhost:8090/++vh++https:<dnsname>:443/++/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/++vh++https:<dnsname>:443/++/$1 [P]
```

The `<dnsname>` part needs to be changed. In this case if it should be `management.domain.com` but Landscape links/forms go to `management`, then the current value is probably `management` and you'll want to change it to `management.domain.com` and reload apache2.

This is for the web UI links and redirects, the SSL certificate's names matching up is a separate issue.